# find a class under $(this) and then replace its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code bellow is part of on click actions. My goal is replace "aaaaa" value with "bbbbb" value under $(this) function. I mean i want to find class name called- "amzTitle" then replace with text value "bbbbb". The jquery code i already tried but syntax error. Any idea to fix?

html:

```
<td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left" width="30%">
<h5><a href="https://www.example.com" id="" target="_blank" class="amzTitle">aaaaa</a></h5>
</td>
```

jquery:

```
$(this).find().className("amzTitle").text("bbbbb");
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".amzTitle").text("bbbbb");`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find/ https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors The long term fix is to understand error messages and read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has no `className()` method. Instead you should provide the class selector as an argument to `find()`:

```
$(this).find('.amzTitle').text('bbbbb');
```

This is obviously assuming that `this` is a reference to a parent element of `.amzTitle`

I'd suggest reading the documentation for jQuery as it's very comprehensive: http://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: do i need to select a tag under that class since its an a tag?

Comment: No, you're selecting the `a` tag directly by that class. It may also be worth you reading the jQuery introductory pages to get a better understanding of how it works: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a 2 parameter selector:

```
$(".amzTitle", this).text("bbbbb");
```